# What is the equivalent of a Visualforce page in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, lightning-experience

This seems like a basic question to me but I have not been able to find an example or anything explaining this:

When in Lightning Experience, what replaces a Visualforce page that serves some custom business logic for an sObject? This is more than a component dropped onto the layout because the view needs the full screen real estate. I first thought this would be a lightning app, but there does not seem to be a way to link to these and they take you out of the Lightning Experience?

The only option I can find is to use a Visualforce page that uses lightning out to load my custom lightning component for my view. This gives my view the full screen and retains the sidebar and header from the Lightning Experience. It seems like there has to be a better way to do this that does not involve wrapping my components in VF pages, anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
D.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got bumped up to the top... anyway there is now a way to do this as of Summer '18: Lightning Components that implement `lightning:isUrlAddressable`. See here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation

You can navigate to the URL and pass initial state parameters (including record ID) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lightning App Builder to create Lightning Pages. As of Summer '16 they can be used to customize home, record home as well as stand alone pages added to the navigation menu. See https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab.htm

Comment: It looks like this is close, but I can't figure out how to enter a Lightning App Page from the context of an sObject (i.e. a custom button on the Opportunity record layout).

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry it is currently not possible to link to Lightning Pages created in App Builder that way. Does it have to take over the whole page? One way could be to add your component to a new tab on record home.